# load JSON data as per Key after certain time

Tags: javascript, json

Hi
I am having an issue with `JSON` key. Say I am having an external `JSON` file like as

```
{
   "key 1":[
      {
         "linkName":"key name 1.1",
         "linkUrl":"key URL 1.1"
      },
      {
         "linkName":"key name 1.2",
         "linkUrl":"key URL 1.2"
      }
   ],
   "key 2":[
      {
         "linkName":"key name 2.1",
         "linkUrl":"key URL 2.1"
      }
   ],
   "key 3":[
      {
         "linkName":"key name 3.1",
         "linkUrl":"key URL 3.1"
      },
      {
         "linkName":"key name 3.2",
         "linkUrl":"key URL 3.2"
      }
   ]
}
```

Also, say I have a `setInterval` function,  the data should load keywise, i.e. after page load, `key 1` is the default, then after certain time `key 2` data loads then again after certain time, `key 3` data loads and so on. I m trying the script as under:

```
$.getJSON("demo.json",function(data){
   $.each(data,function(key,value){
     if(data.hasOwnProperty(key)){
       var total = new Array();
       for(var i=0; i<2; i++){
       total[i] = key;
       $("#topmost").append('<div>'+total+'</div>');
     }
   }
});
});
```

topmost is a div only in the `body/html` as

```
<div id="topmost"></div>
```

Please provide the needful assistance.

Comment: Have you tried using the keys excluding the space character? Something like: {
"key1": [{"linkName": "key name 1.1", "linkUrl": "key URL 1.1" }, {"linkName": "key name 1.2,"linkUrl": "key URL 1.2"} ],
"key2": [{"linkName": "key name 2.1", "linkUrl": "key URL 2.1"}],
"key3": [{"linkName": "key name 3.1", "linkUrl": "key URL 3.1"}, {"linkName": "key name 3.2", "linkUrl": "key URL 3.2"}]
}

Comment: yes, the thing is, when I m checking the key values via alert it is fine, but after every certain interval (say 5 seconds), the alert shows all the 3 keys....

Comment: That would be nice if you provide the full code including the interval, that way it would be possible to test your exact code and look for the problem.

Comment: What is your question? You said you have a problem but you did not describe what it is.

Comment: @Rojan: Will it be possible for me to have your email id so that I can send you the desired files ?

Comment: Sure Sojaner in the Gmail. ;)

Comment: Dropped an email from my gmail id with the desired files. :)
thanks in anticipation....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved your problem.
Here is the code you sent me (Partly pasted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){       
        $.getJSON("demonew2.json",function(data){
            $.each(data,function(key,value){
                $("#topmost").append('<div>'+key+'</div>');
                if(data.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                    //alert(key);
                    var total = new Array();
                    for(var i=0; i<4; i++){ // Here 4 should be something like counts of the keys, as in this json file it is 4
                        total[i] = key;
                        $("#topmost").append('<div>'+total+'</div>');

                        setInterval (function(){alert(key)},5000);
                        // I NEED THE DATA TO BE LOADED KEY BY KEY, SAY AFTER PAGE LOAD IT WILL DISPLAY THE VALUES OF key_1, THEN AFTER 5 SECONDS<br />
                        // IT SHOULD DISPLAY key_2 VALUES AND SO ON.
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div style="background:#ccc; border:2px solid #ccc; padding:10px;" id="topmost"></div>

</body>
```

There are 2 major problems laying in your code:

1) If you want a job to be done after a delay, you have to use "setTimeout" and not "setInterval" that repeats the job with the given interval.
2) using the same delay amount for all jobs will force them to be done almost the same moment so you have to increase the delay amount.

Additionally it would not be a good idea to pass the value directly to the setTimeout or setInterval methods as they start a new thread and there may be abnormal behaviors on cross-thread value injections, so I prefer using a proxy function to avoid ther direct injection and so here is the final working code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $.getJSON("demonew2.json", function (data) {

                var delay = 0;

                $.each(data, function (key, value) {

                    delay += 5000;

                    showData(key, value, delay);
                });
            });
        });

        function showData(key, value, delay) {

            setTimeout(function () {

                $("#topmost").append('<div>' + key + " = " + JSON.stringify(value) + '</div>');

            }, delay);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="background:#ccc; border:2px solid #ccc; padding:10px;" id="topmost"></div>
</body>
```

So let me know if this solved your problem or not.
Have fun. ;)

Update:
I added the full page code for you to use it easily, also changed the append part a little to have a fade effect and make it a little more fun:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $.getJSON("demonew2.json", function (data) {

                var delay = 0;

                $.each(data, function (key, value) {

                    delay += 5000;

                    showData(key, value, delay);
                });
            });
        });

        function showData(key, value, delay) {

            setTimeout(function () {

                $("#topmost").fadeOut(function() {
                $("#topmost").append('<div>' + key + " = " + JSON.stringify(value) + '</div>').fadeIn();
            });

            }, delay);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="background:#ccc; border:2px solid #ccc; padding:10px;" id="topmost"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy :)
The only thing I now wanted is to continue it looping, but, anyways I will do it. The main thing was to get it 1 at a time and u did it
Thanks very much .... :)